# Joomla 3.x - how do I have students (we register them) access one area, and public (self registration) another area?

Tags: joomla

Apologies for what is I suspect an easy question for many - I am very new to Joomla.  I am building a website for my wife on Joomla 3.x (Noteworthymusictuition.co.uk).  I already have an area for her music students, in which they log in and can access teaching material not available to the public.  We register them.

I want to create an area of 'free downloads' for members of the public to self-register and automatically go to an area for them to download material.  They need to be able to log in again after registration.  To build up a newsletter group, I want to capture the registrations and store them for subsequent emails.

I do struggle to understand the ACL in Joomla, but if I try and set up a registration form for the public to use, I have to enable self registration in the admin and that affects the existing student login.

I hope that's enough detail!  I was wondering whether I need an extension to enable multiple levels, such as Access Manager Pro?  But on the other hand, what I'm asking for doesn't really sound like rocket science!

Many thanks!

By the way, I have never done any programming in Joomla - apart from occasional HTML editing.

Anthony

Comment: you can make a special category group for students and for those specific page when any body enter there you can check the special group.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose the 'self' registration option that doesn't stop you creating users as you do now. As long as you set the user up correctly they should be able to log in without issue.

New users would have the option to create an account and would be activated via a confirmation email.

You need to create at least one new user group though. For example, a 'download' group which has access to the additional material. Then, if you use a decent component (http://www.joomlatools.com/extensions/docman/ - see access control *new* tab) you will be able to control access to documents and downloads by specifying which groups are able to see download links etc.

Hope that helps a bit!